# Building a web map with spatial search functionality

Tags: web-mapping, software-recommendations, search

I have some population and thefts data as below:

[image]

I am able to geocode these and build a map of county polygons in QGIS with the attributes attached.

However, my final objective is to have a web map where the user should be able to type in a zip code which returns the number of total thefts and growth of thefts for all counties within a 50 mile radius. We need the map to be accessible on a ipad as well.

what tool to use for building such a web map?

Comment: Would you have a 50 mile buffer around a zip code polygon? or a 50 miles radius from the centroid of the zip code polygon? zip codes can be very irregularly shaped. Would it be better to just use an address?

Answer (score 3):

You do not necessarily need to draw a map if you are working with an entered zip code.

[Turf.js](http://turfjs.org) which was made for working with JavaScript mapping however could be really useful.

The [aggregate](http://turfjs.org/static/docs/module-turf_aggregate.html) function could be helpful you here if you can use the counterpoints of counties. You could also use polygons, but it will be more complicated.

Simply using center points:

- Create GeoJSONs for both your zips and county data with polygons.
- Select point from zips with the [`turf.filter`](http://turfjs.org/static/docs/module-turf_filter.html) function.
- Create your 50 mile radius from the point with [`turf.buffer`](http://turfjs.org/static/docs/module-turf_buffer.html)
- Use [`turf.aggregate`](http://turfjs.org/static/docs/module-turf_buffer.html) to get polygons with the sums of the attributes.

A bit more complicated way if you wish to use polygons:

- Create GeoJSONs for both your zips and county data with polygons.
- Select zip polygon with `turf.filter`.
- Create your 50 mile radius buffer with `turf.buffer`.
- Create variables to hold your totals for each attribute with 0.
- For each county use [`turf.intersect`](http://turfjs.org/static/docs/module-turf_intersect.html) with your 50 mile buffer to check that it doesn't return `undefined` (or that it returns a polygon). If your buffer and county overlap add each of the county attributes to the totals.

If you wish to display a map you could input your filtered ZIP code point/polygon, your buffered polygon, and the aggregated/intersected polygons.

Additionally you could replace using `turf.filter` and your own zip GeoJSON with using a lookup service like [Mapbox geocoding](https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/#geocoding) which will also work with addresses or town names.

Answer (score 1):

[MangoMap](https://mangomap.com) has that feature out of the box. Here's a map that demonstrates the tool:

http://mangomap.com/maps/51645/Query-Tool

Disclaimer: I'm a founder of Mango ;-)